# Sending HTML elements through Mails

Tags: asp.net

I want to open a mail client on click of a link.
I am using this code:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:email address?subject=[subject text]&body=http://google.com'>here");

its opening the mail client but I am unable to get the link(here).It should come as a link. Is there any way to do it through IsBodyHtml=true?
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you are doing there is creating a mailto: link which is just passed to the default email client to process. Although most email clients support address, subject and body I don't think there's any way to force a particular body format, it's entirely up to the client application what it does with that content.

Would changing it to "please visit http://google.com" not suffice? Most email clients will automatically hyperlink anything that looks like a link when you read the email.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the users default mailclient just use a mailto link

```
<a href="mailto:asdf@asdf.com">text</a>
```

I don't really understand where and when you are running the "Proccess.Start" code but if you want to open a mailclient though the browser a "mailto"-link is the way to go.

You can set subject for the email that opens but that's about it (depending on default mailclient). Doing more like sending etc. would be a securityrisk.

If you need to do more complex things create a form instead for the user to fill in.

Comment: forcing a mailclient to start in pageload etc, would also be a securityrisk and i sure don't want MY browser to be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks Markus,but even when I am directly using mailto,I am unable to send HTMl elemnts? what i want to know is it possible to send <a> in mail clients through mailto.w8ing for ur reply.

Comment: We need to sort out if you want to send an email or want the visitor on your site to send an email. 

If you want to send an email have a look at the "MailMessage" class.
If you want to popp up the "compose" window of the visitors default mailclient you cannot control which format they use.